# NameError: name 'Con' is not defined

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, map-algebra, nameerror

I have 365 rasters with the same extent, and I am trying to sum them together by month. I have the script below, which was working until I added the line `out1 = Con(IsNull(raster), 0, raster)` which is supposed to get rid of any nodata cells in each raster I am processing. Now my script keeps raising the exception:

`NameError: name 'Con' is not defined.`

I am using the Con function exactly as it is used in all of the ArcGIS help documentations, so I understand why it doesn't recognize `Con`.

Anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this error? My script is below.

```
#script to create scaled habitat maps

#import  modules
import arcpy

#check out spatial analyst extension
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
else:
    arcpy.AddError("Spatial Analyst extension is unavailable. Please check to see if you have the Spatial Analyst License.")

from arcpy import env
rasters = "Z:/sharks/Models/Summer2013/RF/ALL/SB_RF/NSMPpresRFPdh/AR_NSMPpresRFPdh/outputRasters"
env.workspace = rasters
listRasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
listRasters.sort()
listRasters
janRasters = listRasters[0:30]
febRasters = listRasters[31:58]
marRasters = listRasters[59:89]
aprRasters = listRasters[90:119]
mayRasters = listRasters[120:150]
junRasters = listRasters[151:180]
julRasters = listRasters[181:211]
augRasters = listRasters[212:242]
sepRasters = listRasters[243:272]
octRasters = listRasters[273:303]
novRasters = listRasters[304:333]
decRasters = listRasters[334:364]

rasterList = [janRasters, febRasters, marRasters, aprRasters, mayRasters, junRasters, julRasters, augRasters, sepRasters, octRasters, novRasters, decRasters]
nameList = ["janHabitat.img", "febHabitat.img", "marHabitat.img", "aprHabitat.img", "mayHabitat.img", "junHabitat.img", "julHabitat.img", "augHabitat.img", "sepHabitat.img", "octHabitat.img", "novHabitat.img", "decHabitat.img"]

counter = 0            
for list in rasterList:
    i = 0
    print ("processing list: %s" % (list,))
    for raster in list:
        print ("processing raster: %s" %(raster,))
        #convert nodata to zero
        out1 = Con(IsNull(raster), 0, raster)

        #sum rasters together
        if i == 0:
            outSUM = arcpy.Raster(raster)
            i += 1
        else:
            outSUM = outSUM + raster
            i += 1

    #save final output to the current workspace
    outSUM.save("Z:/sharks/Models/Summer2013/RF/ALL/SB_RF/NSMPpresRFPdh/AR_NSMPpresRFPdh/monthlyHabitat/" + nameList[counter])
    counter +=1
```

Comment: Might I suggest you emulate the example in the [manual page for `CON`](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/)? I notice immediately that it imports `arcpy.sa` whereas your code does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't use arcpy but I know Python. This only means that you need to import the Python module with Con (and it is not arcpy alone)

If I look at, [Con (Spatial Analyst)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm), I see that it is a function of the Spatial Analyst module and the examples provide the solution. You have forgotten to import the module:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
```

But the "pythonic" way to do is:

```
from arcpy.sa import Con
```

Comment: Oh okay thank you so much, I am really sorry about asking a question that was a careless mistake on my part!

Comment: @Liza, That is what this site is here for.  It's how we learn.